# How to make a mp3 player play songs when i click on them from my <a> tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css, audio, media-player

I made a list of songs in my `<a>` tags, and I want the mp3 player to be universal for every song, so when i *click* on one song(link) from the list it would be played on the player, and it wouldn't have to refresh the page, or open it in another tab to play the song?

Here is my **HTML**:

```
<audio preload="auto" src="#"></audio>

<a class="trigger" href="#" data-src="audio/song1.mp3">Song #1</a>
<a class="trigger" href="#" data-src="audio/song2.mp3">Song #2</a>
<a class="trigger" href="#" data-src="audio/song3.mp3">Song #3</a>
<a class="trigger" href="#" data-src="audio/song4.mp3">Song #4</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged the question with jQuery, you can simply use that to set the `src` attribute of your `audio` element.  Something like this:

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
    $('audio').prop('src', $(this).data('src'));
});
```